# compute $aba^{−1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

With the usual notations, compute $aba^{−1}$
in $S_5$ and express it as the
product of disjoint cycles, where
$a = (1 2 3)(4 5)$ and $b = (2 3)(1 4).$

My attempt :  $ab$ = $(1345)$ and $a^{-1} = (321)(54)$

now now i got  $aba^{-1} = (12)(35)$

is its correct ?

Any hint/ solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct, since $ab=(1\ \ 5\ \ 4\ \ 2)$. Actually,$$aba^{-1}=(1\ \ 3)(2\ \ 5).$$

Comment: ..@Jose carlos sir  u take from right side   or left side ? i mean   count from left side or right side ?

Comment: From the right side, of course. This is just composition of functions, and $(f\circ g)(x)$ *means* $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: But in  Herstein/Artin   they count from left side  im confused ?  as  gallian count from right side  which one  is applicable ??

Comment: I am using the standard notation here.

Comment: But  if we  talked in General ....we  count  from  left  side  or  right side ? which  one correct  right or left ?

Comment: How to compute $(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 3)$? Let us see whae this does to $1$. First, $(1\ \ 3)$ maps $1$ into $3$ and then $(1\ \ 2)$ maps $3$ into itself. So, $(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 3)$ maps $1$ into $3$. And what about $3$? First, $(1\ \ 3)$ maps $3$ into $1$ and then $(1\ \ 2)$ maps $1$ into $2$. So, $(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 3)$ maps $3$ into $2$. And what about $2$? First, $(1\ \ 3)$ maps $2$ into itself and then $(1\ \ 2)$ maps $2$ into $1$. So, $(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 3)$ maps $2$ into $1$. Therefore, $(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 3)=(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)$.

Comment: thanks u sir  i got its @Jose carlos  sir

Answer (score 1):

Computing conjugates in $\mathfrak S_5$ is very easy. If $c=(i_1 \, i_2 \dots i_k)$ is a cycle then $\sigma c \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(i_1) \, \sigma(i_2) \dots \sigma(i_k))$. In your case, this yields $$aba^{-1} = (a(2)a(3))(a(1)a(4)) = (31)(25).$$

Comment: how  $a(2) =3$?..

Comment: You need to remember that the product between cycles is simply composition of applications. On the one hand you have $(45)(2)=2$, and on the other hand $(123)(2)=3$, so $a(2)=(123)(45)(2)=(123)(2)=3$.